# Solr - termfreq partial matches

Tags: search, solr, match, keyword

I'm using Solr to query a set of documents and I want to get the number of matches for certain term, right now I'm using

`termfreq(text,'manage')`

However this does not hit on `Manager` or `Management`

`termfreq(text,'manage*')`

returns the same count. I've tried using different tokenizers, some won't even accept the `*` and I haven't found one that returns the correct number of matches.

**Field:**

`<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" required="false"/>`

Is there a way I can get `termfreq` to also count partial matches?

Comment: be careful for what you ask... "partial matches" in general is not a good idea, for example do you want "up" to match "cup"? "uplift"? "supper"? "cupertino"? 
A typical solution is to search for word "stems"(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some custom tokenizers and and filter classes to the analyzer.

In your /shared/field_types.xml file, create a new type like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And in /shared/fields.xml:

```
<field name="text" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/> 
<dynamicField name="*_text" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

And use that as "text" as the type of the field.

A more advanced solution:

```
 <fieldType name="startsWith" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!-- remove words/chars we don't care about -->
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
      <!-- now remove any extra space we have, since spaces WILL influence matching -->
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\s+" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\s+" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

In /shared/fields.xml:

```
<dynamicField name="*_starts_with" stored="true" type="startsWith" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

Then, in the top level of your core's schema.xml add this:

```
<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="../../../shared/fields.xml"/>
<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="../../../shared/field_types.xml"/>
```

And add this to your copyFields in the core's schema.xml:

```
 <copyFields>
      <copyField source="yourField" dest="yourField_text"/>
      <copyField source="yourField" dest="yourField_starts_with"/>
      ...
 </copyFields>
```

Comment: both of these methods cause termfreq to return count of zero, not it's not even counting exact matches lol

Comment: Which field are you using for termfreq, yourField or yourField_Text/yourField_starts_with? Notice that these examples are assuming you didn't actually name your index field "text."

Comment: I copied ur code exactly from the advanced solution on down. I'm using yourField (in my case that field is called `textRaw`) now it is returning exact matches but it's still not counting partial matches. using yourField_starts_with yields no matches

Comment: You will probably want to use the simple solution. Make aure your field is of type "text"

Comment: this simple solution is what I have been using already, it works but only counts exact matches...

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I needed to count the termfreq, which also should match on subparts of words.
Add this FieldType solved it.

```
<fieldType name="startWith" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```